# Internet Explorer ul li behind image

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, z-index, html-lists

I'm working on a site someone else built and there's a bug with the navigation menu on IE. When you hover over the dropdown, the list falls behind an image instead of over it. It looks fine on every other browser. The site is using jQuery and another library called Nav.js, both of which I know almost nothing about. I'm assuming there's a Z-Index to be adjusted somewhere? I appreciate your help.

**Edit** I can't post pictures because I'm a new member. You can see my problem [here](http://hyperhidrosis.com/new/index.html).

This is the HTML:

```
              <!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/Nav.lbi" --><ul class="topnav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="surgical_treatments.html">Treatments</a>             
  <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="hand_sweat.html">Sweaty Hands / Sweaty Palms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="facial_sweating.html">Facial Sweating</a></li>
                    <li><a href="facial_blushing.html">Facial Blushing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="axillary_sweating.html">Axillary Sweating</a></li>
              </ul>             
             </li>
  <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>            </li>
  <li><a href="side_effects.html">Side Effects</a></li>
  <li><a href="alternatives.html">Alternative Treatments</a></li>

  <li><a href="hospitals.html">Hospitals</a></li>
  <li><a href="surgeons.html">Surgeons</a>
  <ul class="subnav">
                    <li><a href="dr_baumgartner.html">Dr. Fritz Baumgartner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_bell.html">Dr. Roger Bell</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_cameron.html">Dr. Alan Cameron</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_connery.html">Dr. Cliff P. Connery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_duarte.html">Dr. Jo&atilde;o B. V. Duarte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_edelman.html">Dr. David S. Edelman</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_garcia-morato.html">Dr. Joaqu&iacute;n Garc&iacute;a-Morato</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_giudiceandrea.html">Dr. Alberto Giudiceandrea</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_konecny.html">Dr. Jiri Konecny</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_chien-chi-lin.html">Dr. Chien-Chi-Lin</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_mikhail.html">Dr. Peter Mikhail</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_revuelta.html">Dr. Jos&eacute; Revuelta</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dr_zeldin.html">Dr. Robert Zeldin</a></li> 
      </ul>             
  </li>
  <li><a href="payment_methods.html">Payment, Insurance</a></li>
  <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
  <li><a href="hyper_contact_form.html">Contact Form</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/btn_english.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="espanol/index.html"><img src="images/btn_spanish.jpg" alt="" border="0" /></a></li>
            </ul>
<!-- #EndLibraryItem --><div id="slider">
   <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
   <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul.topnav li ul.subnav { 
    z-index: 999;
    visibility:visible;
     }

     ul.topnav h3 {
         padding-left:10px;
         font-size:30px;
         }

ul.topnav {
    font-weight:bold;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 975px;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: url(../images/bg_topnav.jpg) repeat-x;
    padding-left: 5px;
    height: 35px;
}
ul.topnav li {
    font-weight:normal;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative; /*--Declare X and Y axis base--*/
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
ul.topnav li a{
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    color: #937600;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    font-size:13px;
}
ul.topnav li a:hover{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFF;
}
ul.topnav li span { /*--Drop down trigger styles--*/
    width: 17px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    background: url(../images/btn_subnav.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
ul.topnav li span.subhover {background-position: center bottom; cursor: pointer;} /*--Hover effect for trigger--*/
ul.topnav li ul.subnav {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute; /*--Important - Keeps subnav from affecting main navigation flow--*/
    left: 0;
    top: 35px;
    background-color: #E0C60E;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #6606101;
}
ul.topnav li ul.subnav li{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e7ca48; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cfb70f; /*--Create bevel effect--*/
    clear: both;
    width: 240px;
}
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a {
    float: left;
    width: 215px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background:10px center;
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
    background-image: url(../images/bg_subnavy.jpg);
}
html ul.topnav li ul.subnav li a:hover { /*--Hover effect for subnav links--*/
    background:10px center;
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
    background-image: url(../images/bg_subnavb.jpg); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same problem, hopefully the same solution!
http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Comment: Thanks for the link but it seems that only works when you're using absolute positioning. Even when I make the items absolute it does not work.

Comment: I played around with this some more and it worked, I just had not given the parent element both a z-index and an absolute position. Lifesaver, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad this solved your problem! If an answer answers your question, mark it as final answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had to adjust the z-index (in the css) of all the conatiner divs relating to the menu: eg. #header & #menu etc.